# Keeping mapboxgl-js popup open with listeners bound to mouse movement

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am drawing a map with routes (LineString) on them and I am handling

- mouse hover (through `setFeatureState`) to make them look thicker
- mouse click - to select a route and show some information outside of the map

In a case where two routes are detected under a click (`e.features.length > 1`) I want to show a `new Popup({ closeButton: true })`, with disambiguation info/links so that user can precisely select the route they want.

Unfortunately, tracking the mouse movement causes the popup to disappear when user tries to enter the popup area to click the links within.

So what I am doing is, I am unbinding the mouse move listeners before showing the popup, and re-binding on close

```
showPopup(mapbox){
  this.removeListeners(mapbox);

  const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: true,
    closeOnClick: true,
  });

  popup.once('close', () => {
    this.addListeners(mapbox);
  });
}
```

Is there any better API way to solve that?

Comment: Can you include more of your code, such as the mouse-over handlers?

Comment: Thanks. The code is strewn around a couple of classes (a component, a container and a directive), thus very complex to quote here. I have pinned the problem down though. In my app `setFeatureState()` can be invoked by hovering a corresponding item in a list outside of the map. So I need to invoke change detection manually (`appRef.tick()` in my case). What causes the popup to disappear is not the mouseover/out handlers themselves, but `appRef.tick()`. I cannot afford to remove `.tick()`, so momentarily unbinding the handlers looks like the only working solution.